# Angular CLI - Only one Bundle.js

Tags: javascript, angular, bundle, angular-cli

I try for the first time the Angular 2 CLI Tool and I want to know if there was a command to generate a single bundle.js file for an angular CLI project (also change the location of images and css to structure my project).

[Structure when i create and config angular project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0VO8.png)

The problem is that I don't have access to the webpack.config. With an "ng eject" we get the file but we can no longer manage the project with the command line.

Someone knows if there is a command line or if there is a simplified webpack.config file that doesn't 400 line.

Comment: not possible with angular-cli, however, you can write a simple script to concatenate the js bundles into one. You can use native node api's or this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been talked about at lengths over on the [CLI github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1656).

As it stands the CLI team have decided to not expose the inner `webpack.config.js`.

However they have acknowledged the communities concerns for webpack customisation and will address it in the future.